# How to simulate the user click on a column header of a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to simulate thru code the user clicking on a header of a WPF datagrid column (using .Net 4 in case it matters).

Is this possible?

Comment: what aspect of "simulate" are you after? the end-result or the UI?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I need the user to see the control at the first time as if it clicked one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the AutomationPeer classes, which are designed for this sort of thing, specifically the [DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.datagridcolumnheaderitemautomationpeer.aspx).

```
 DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer peer = new DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer (Your_control);
 IInvokeProvider invoker= (IInvokeProvider)peer;
 invoker.Invoke(); // Invoke a click programmatically
```

Comment: There is no contructor with one parameter and the other requested parameters are not clear what they should be, never saw the Automation namespace and there is not much info available. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: I had used the Button AutomationPeer class before it it worked great.  When I browsed the namespace on MSDN and saw there were several dedicated to the DataGrid, I assumed they would work as well.  I think your best bet is to just study the documentation more closely and google for some examples on how to use them, I can't give you the exact code because I haven't used these specific classes.