# Simulate a click on datagrid header column

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I was looking for and found: [How to simulate the user click on a column header of a datagrid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400714/how-to-simulate-the-user-click-on-a-column-header-of-a-datagrid-in-wpf), but I don't know what I must put in "your_control", I'm using Silverlight 5, can somebody help me??

```
DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer peer = new DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer (Your_control);
```

my DataGrid is dgEmployee

When I try use it, defining it so:

```
DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer peer = new DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer (dgEmployee);
```

System send me an error:

**"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer.DataGridColu‌​mnHeaderAutomationPeer(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)' has some invalid arguments"**

How I can put the DataGridColumnHeader of my dgEmployee as argument?

Thanks!!

Comment: It appears there is no constructor with single parameter from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.datagridcolumnheaderitemautomationpeer.datagridcolumnheaderitemautomationpeer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel but when I try use it, system send me an error: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)' has some invalid arguments" then how I can put the DataGridColumnHeader of my dgEmployee

Comment: What was the error? update your question with that info

Comment: I have no idea about this but looks like it expects `DataGridColumnHeader` which you can get from `column.Header` I hope.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel   in fact, I put it so: 
`DataGridColumn col = (DataGridColumn)dgPlantilla.SelectedItem;` 
                                `System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer peer = new DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer(col.Header);`
and this is when I make the mistake

Comment: I noticed `column.Header` is of type object. Did you add a cast?

Comment: Did you try `new DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer((DataGridColumnHeader)col.Header);` You may need a cast, since object can't be passed in over there

Comment: oh my god...ok, but what exactly should be col.Header, because I put `System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer peer =
                                    new DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer((System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)dgPlantilla.Columns[0].Header);` and yes I may, but at execution time, show me an error: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader'.** :(

Comment: Declare your column like this and try `<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Hello"> </DataGridColumnHeader>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>`

Comment: and so? this is in XAML, but in my app I declare a class, with a process I fill data, and then I make dgEmployee.ItemSource = lstemployees; so the datagrid columns are created automatic. Anyway, if I declare the columns in XAML as you say, then how would I put the instruction    "DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer peer = new DataGridColumnHeaderItemAutomationPeer (**Your_control**);"

Comment: Check to see if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) helps. If not don't hesitate to raise another question.

Comment: already checked, but this does not help me, I just need to know: if my DataGrid dgEmployee has 3 columns and I want to refer to the first column, how I ask for his DataGridColumnHeader? 
eg **dgEmployee.Columns[0].Header** gives me the title containing the first column, in my case: "ID", but what about with his DataGridColumnHeader?

Comment: what I need is the **DataGridColumnHeader OBJECT**

Comment: I found the answer in my msdn post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/78ae21b6-1fa7-45c0-95d5-7b84f0e7aff4/how-to-get-datagridcolumnheader-object-from-datagrid-?forum=silverlightgen, maybe can do helpful

Comment: So that works? Good.. You can add it as a answer here and accept it yourself.

Comment: I posted it in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/78ae21b6-1fa7-45c0-95d5-7b84f0e7aff4/how-to-get-datagridcolumnheader-object-from-datagrid-?forum=silverlightgen, is very long and I don't know how to put it here, nor do I know where I have to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader headerObj;

headerObj = GetColumnHeaderFromColumn(myDataGrid, myDataGrid.Columns[1].Header);

System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer peer =
                                new DataGridColumnHeaderAutomationPeer(headerObj);
                            IInvokeProvider invoker = (IInvokeProvider)peer;
                            invoker.Invoke(); // Invoke a click programmatically   


    private System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader GetColumnHeaderFromColumn(DependencyObject parent, object header)
    {            
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child != null)
            {
                if (child is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = child as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader;
                    if (header.Equals(columnHeader.Content))
                    {
                        return columnHeader;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = GetColumnHeaderFromColumn(child, header);
                    if (null != columnHeader)
                    {
                        return columnHeader;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

maybe can be helpful for somebody, regards from Mexico